# Struts2 better URLs with dot inside

Tags: java, url, struts2, restful-url, pretty-urls

Let's say we need to get a login form with pre-defined username.

So if user goes to url:

```
//somehost:8080/myapp/auth/myusername
```

the action should take `myusername` as input parameter.

I tried http://www.struts2.info/blog/better-urls-with-struts2 as example, and it works great.

But if `myusername` contains dots, like:

```
//somehost:8080/myapp/auth/firstname.lastname
```

, I get 404 error.

Is there any simple solution to use dots as a part of url parameter ?

Comment: Did you try giving it in quotes.<br>
like //somehost:8080/myapp/auth/'firstname.lastname '<br>
not sure though...<br>

Comment: Because it thinks you are trying to get an action with extension .lastname, you need to write a rule for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **struts.xml**:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""  />
```

and in **web.xml**:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Untested, but it should work

Comment: @never: @AndreaLigios: Empty value isn't best for the `struts.action.extension`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12607075/1700321.

Comment: An empty setting wont work for his/her use case though. The other alternative would be to use a custom `ActionMapper`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Woah, september 2012... I missed that, +1. So if I got that right, `""` means EVERYTHING (including static res), while `","` means only actions with no extensions (*and* static resources without extension, not standard but can happen); adding `","` will not work then for this use-case, because `.lastname` will be threated as an action extension, and filtered (as @StevenBenitez pointed out). Then, unless using a custom ActionMapper, the only shot for OP question is to use `""` and avoid using struts2 to serve static resources... is this right ?