# Multiple URL extensions, individual action/controller mapping in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, xml-configuration

Is it possible in Struts2 to map URL/actions to different extensions? e.g. if my app is hosted as

```
http://stack.com/myapp
```

Can I have 2 URLs

```
http://stack.com/myapp/act.action
```

and

```
http://stack.com/myapp/donoact.do
```

with no mapping for `/act.do` and `/donoact.action`. i.e. a URL should be available on single extension.

Using `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,do" />` makes the URLs available on both extensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12607075/1700321.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply Aleksandr. But the above doesn't address my problem. Actually I need to apply security and other filters on *.action URLs and bypass *.do. If I use "action.extension" constant URL's are available on both extensions. I don't want that

Comment: So you want some actions with .do and some with .action? Namespaces are usually used for security constraints and filters.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Which is your real use-case ? Which distinction are you trying to make by using most likely the wrong instrument (the extension) ? **Beware of [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/214186)**

Comment: I agree Andrea. Thanks Aleksandr, namespace seems a better approach to the solution. I have suggested the solution to my client, let's see what they agree upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can map an action by name and namespace, but can't map by extension. When Struts2 default [`ActionMapper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapper.html) is determined an action name from the URL it strips the extension and place a namespace and action name using separate properties of [`ActionMapping`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapping.html).

Lately, this action mapping is used to find the action config used to build and invoke the action instance.

See more about [`action configuration`](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html) on Struts docs site.