# struts '.action' not defaulting into URL

Tags: struts2

I'm wondering why my Struts application would direct me to

```
https://myhost.com/myThing/myThing?pickListId=2000000011
```

instead of:

```
https://myhost.com/myThing/myThing.action?pickListId=2000000011
```

Shouldn't these show the same thing? The top URL directs me to the 404 page and the bottom works correctly.

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to guess. How is the link being *generated???*

Comment: To achieve the first, you must configure it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12629951/1654265

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. It turned out in my web.xml my filter mappings were only directing urls containing `.action` to Struts. I just needed to change the filter mappings so all requests were allowed to go to Struts.