# 404 error when Struts2 action extension is set to empty

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, action-mapping

I want to remove the action suffix extension in Struts2 application.

Added `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>` to the `struts.xml`
but Apache server throws 404 error.

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action
>   name [login.jsp] associated with context path [/Ideck_V3].

I'm using `welcome-file-list` in `web.xml` for the first page.
Here is `web.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.hbs.ideck.common.Struts2Dispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the `struts.xml`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/> 
    <include file="user.xml"/>
    <include file="vendor.xml"/>
    <include file="settings.xml"/>
</struts>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 .action extension causing CSS, JavaScript and Struts Dojo to break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607075/struts2-action-extension-causing-css-javascript-and-struts-dojo-to-break)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default extension mapping is `",,action"`. It means that you can use mapping to action name with `.action` suffix and without it, so if you want to remove the action suffix extension you need to specify it in `struts.xml` as

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>
```

Note, the mapping to action without action suffix still remains. It allows to resolve extensions in the url like `.jsp` and don't mess it up with action name.

Comment: How careless am I to check only the content not the comments.Thanks for the explanation.http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-remove-the-action-suffix-extension-in-struts-2/

Answer (score 1):

As you dont set any extension for your actions, everything in "/*" (see your web.xml) is intercepted. If you want to filter everything and dont set any extension, everything will be an action for struts.

You can try do filter only a path

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/actions/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or you have to set an extension

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action" />
```

Or exclude some patterns

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="A REGEX"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.