# Struts 2 extension changed, redirect when external link .action

Tags: java, struts2

Using below struts.xml setting, changing action extension from `.action` to `.html` was a success.

`<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html"/>`

However, the old links from Google search results or other external links are still pointed to `.action` url, it always redirect to no page found error when clicked.
Is there anyway I can redirect those `.action` url to latest `.html` links?

Comment: You can put both in the configuration. And see this [Struts2 .action extension causing CSS, JavaScript and Struts Dojo to break](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12607075/1700321).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I resolved it now by adding an Interceptor that will replace the extension .action to .html and redirect it.

Comment: @elfwine Can you add a code for the interceptor?

Comment: @RomanC Sorry for late response, I will post the code at the answer section below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the interceptor that replaces .action url to .html. 
Don't forget to declare the added interceptor in struts.xml.
I hope it will be helpful to others looking for it. ;)

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actioninvocation) throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
    if(url != null && url.indexOf(".action") > 0) {
        String fullUrl = url.toString().replace(".action", ".html");
        String queryString = request.getQueryString();
        fullUrl += (queryString == null ? "" : ("?" + queryString));
        // return new url with .html
        response.sendRedirect(fullUrl);
    }
    return actioninvocation.invoke();
}
```